# Не запускается .exe файл

Tags: c++, c

Я в программировании пока что чайник, только начал изучать, проблема такова:
Написал самую простую программку Hello world (изучаю С С++), всё написал скомпилировал, запускаю через командную строку всё работает вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("hello World!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

но попытавшись запустить EXE фаил он тут же закрывается, а в командной строке всё отлично работает. Вопрос в чём проблема и как решить подскажите!!!!

Comment: Он у вас сразу же закрывается, потому что вы ничего не написали, чтобы он ждал какой-то реакции пользователя.

Comment: Как пример - те же виндовые програмы(команды) ping и ipconfig так работают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто программа исполнилась и закрылась. Если запускать из консоли, `return 0;` в `main()` отдает управление обратно консоле, с кодом 0 (нормальное завершение программы), и можно продолжать роботу. Если надо не закривать окно консоли вызваной через `a.exe`, можно добавить в код `getchar();`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello World!\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Программа завершиться после нажатия Enter.
Или второй вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello World!\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что при "попытке запустить ЕХЕ файл" (очевидно, из среды разработки или из Windows Explorer-a) открывается новое консольное окно, которое автоматически закрывается, когда программа отработала.

```
  ...
  printf("\nPress any key to finish.\n");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтоб файл не закрывался, нужно вызвать сообветствующий метод, в builder это getch(), в вижле _getch(), инклюд conio.h и там и там

Comment: поставь плюсик на ответ)), А ещё лучше отметь как ответ на вопрос